# QTP does not call a specific function during runtime

Tags: vbscript, automation, qtp

For whom who use QTP(Quick test Professional), 
I have a problem, during runtime QTP does not call a specific function and ignore it totally. 
 and niether runtime nor syntax errors are reported.

do any of you had face this problem before ? or any of you can help me in this trouble?

your help is highly appreciated.

thanks
Manaysah

Answer (score 0):

QTP / Script settings:

- Do you run with `Option Explicit` in the top of **all** your libraries
- Do you run with `On Error Goto 0`
- Have you set your Run testsettings (File>Settings>Run) to `Pop up message box` under the 'When error occurs during run session:' field
- Is the library with the function added as resource to the Action

Code:

- What is the function name? Maybe you have chosen an already existing keyword
- What happens if you change the function name to something absolutely unique
- Are you sure the function is not present in another library, so it don't gets overridden
- Is the function name not the same as a variable (or array) in your script
- Did you set your function to Public?

Debug:

- What happens if you call the function directly from your main Action
- What happens if you copy your function in a new Action and call it from that Action